# How to store last visited n pages in cookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I googled for 1-2 hours about storing last visited pages in cookie in PHP. But generally there are JS examples. Can you recommend an example about it which is fully documented or can you give an example?

I'm new for PHP and I want to do some examples.

This example is not working

```
// define the new value to add to the cookie
$ad_name = $myProductId; //comes from $_GET[]

// if the cookie exists, read it and unserialize it. If not, create a blank array
if(array_key_exists('recentviews', $_COOKIE)) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['recentviews'];
    $cookie = unserialize($cookie);
} else {
    $cookie = array();
}

// add the value to the array and serialize
$cookie[] = $ad_name;
$cookie = serialize($cookie);

// save the cookie
setcookie('recentviews', $cookie, time()+3600);

//prints to screen noting
foreach ($_COOKIE['recentviews'] as $h) {
        echo $h."-";

    }
```

Comment: what the hell? why -1

Comment: Are you doing all of this cookie setting before outputting any html content (or whitespace)?

Comment: You can also use/debug with: `$result = setcookie(...);` result is true/false depending if it was executed correctly or not.

Answer (score -1):

`$_COOKIE['recentviews']` is still a serialized string so this won't work in a loop.

Working code:

```
// define the new value to add to the cookie
$ad_name = $myProductId; //comes from $_GET[]

// if the cookie exists, read it and unserialize it. If not, create a blank array
if(array_key_exists('recentviews', $_COOKIE)) {
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['recentviews'];
    $cookie = unserialize($cookie);
} else {
    $cookie = array();
}

// add the value to the array and serialize
$cookie[] = $ad_name;
$cookieString = serialize($cookie); /* changed $cookie to $cookieString */

// save the cookie
setcookie('recentviews', $cookieString , time()+3600); /* insert $cookiestring */

//prints to screen noting
foreach ($cookie as $h) { /* changed $_COOKIE['recentviews'] to $cookie */
        echo $h."-";

    }
```

Changes are explained in /* .. */ comments.

Comment: Please elaborate on -1?